# CNN for precipitation and temperature prediction

Tags: conv-neural-network, tf.keras, temperature

Suppose that a region rectangle is a matrix of size `n_lat * n_lon` (pixels). I have the out put of a climate model for the region for `k` days. so my data is of size `n_lat * n_lon * k`.
I have also the observations for the `k` days as matrices `n_lat * n_lon`. Without vectorizing the matrices how can I use CNN to fit to data?

I need a code based on Keras and Tensorflow for constructing a CNN in order to get data in matrix format not columnar and train it. This is a type of regression problem not classification.